# How to change how distance is calculated in a scipy distance matrix?

Tags: python, dataframe, scipy, euclidean-distance, distance-matrix

I have the following dataframe (df):

```
    x   y
0  50  50
1  18  83
2   6  21
3  30  13
4  44  29
5  81  68
```

which corresponds to the x and y coordinates of 6 points.
I am using scipy's **distance_matrix** to create a distance matrix for which I use the following code:

```
DistMatrix = round(pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df.values, df.values), index=df.index, columns=df.index), 1)
```

The result seems correct, but it doesn't look like Euclidean distance is used.

How can i toggle the way distance is calculated (meaning how can I choose between Manhattan Distance or Mahalanobis or Euclidean etc.)?

Comment: You can't use euclidean with scipy from the source its clear that they are using "minkowski_distance" for calculation and there is no choice to change this

Comment: The Minkowski distance with p=2 *is* the Euclidean distance.

Comment: *"The result seems correct, but it doesn't look like Euclidean distance is used."*  Please show the actual result that you get, and explain this comment.  The result should be the Euclidean distance.  Why doesn't the result "look like Euclidean distance"?

Answer (score 2):

Actually by default it's Euclidean distance in scipy. However if you want more flexibility why don't you use [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) distance matrix instead?

It has many other distances or you can use your own distance function instead

The function looks like this:

```
sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances(X, Y=None, metric='euclidean', *, n_jobs=None, force_all_finite=True, **kwds)
```

See the param metric:

```
metric: str or callable, default=’euclidean’
```

> The metric to use when calculating distance between instances in a
> feature array. If metric is a string, it must be one of the options
> allowed by scipy.spatial.distance.pdist for its metric parameter, or a
> metric listed in pairwise.PAIRWISE_DISTANCE_FUNCTIONS. If metric is
> “precomputed”, X is assumed to be a distance matrix. Alternatively, if
> metric is a callable function, it is called on each pair of instances
> (rows) and the resulting value recorded. The callable should take two
> arrays from X as input and return a value indicating the distance
> between them.

Available distance metrics are:

```
‘cosine’
‘euclidean’
‘haversine’
‘manhattan’
‘nan_euclidean’
```

if you insist on scipy then for Manhattan specifically you add `p` param

```
distance_matrix(df.values, df.values, p=1)
```

For Euclidean distance p=2 and it's the default.